# What is a credibility value in meta-analyses?

Tags: meta-analysis

I came across the term credibility value in reference to meta-analytic analyses and am not familiar with it. It is similar to a credibility interval?

Here is the context:

"Because there is more variation in business units pooled across companies than there is within the average company across business units, estimated correlations are larger when true validity estimates are calculated for business units across companies. For instance, consider the estimates relative to the customer satisfaction–loyalty criterion. Without the between company range-restriction correction, the true validity value of overall satisfaction was .23 (True Validity A) with a 90% credibility value (CV) of .17. This is the relation expected within a typical company. With the between-company range-restriction correction (True Validity B), the true validity value of overall satisfaction was .28 with a 90% CV of .21. This is the relation expected in business units pooled across companies (i.e., in the total population of business units)" Harter et al. (2002).

Comment: The quote you give seems a mess. What does it mean by the true value do you think? When it calls it a validity value is it an estimate of a validity coefficient? If the credibility value it estimates is indeed a credible interval then it is an interval with upper limit infinity (or whatever the maximum possible value is) as @user106879 suggests in his/her answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could assume that this meta-analysis is conducted with a Bayesian approach.

A credibility value is sort of a confidence interval with a probability distribution. You can read more here: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval)

Focusing on the second paragraph you can see different methods to choose a credibility value for the interval:

> Credible intervals are not unique on a posterior distribution. Methods for defining a suitable credible interval include:
>   Choosing the narrowest interval, which for a unimodal distribution will involve choosing those values of highest probability density including the mode. This is sometimes called the highest posterior density interval.
>   Choosing the interval where the probability of being below the interval is as likely as being above it. This interval will include the median. This is sometimes called the equal-tailed interval.
>   Assuming that the mean exists, choosing the interval for which the mean is the central point.
>   It is possible to frame the choice of a credible interval within decision theory and, in that context, an optimal interval will always be a highest probability density set.

Comment: That makes sense. Too bad the article does not do a good job of explaining it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a definition in this [article - CUMULATIVE RESEARCH KNOWLEDGE AND
SOCIAL POLICY FORMULATION: The Critical Role
of Meta-Analysis](http://ist-socrates.berkeley.edu/~maccoun/PP279_Hunter.pdf) which says that

> This value is called the 90% credibility value; 90% of
>   all values in the distribution of true validities lie above this value.

Comment: I like this as a simple way of explaining the idea. Thanks!